# Цикл for с декрементированием i в Visual Basic .Net

Tags: циклы, visual-basic

До этого писал на `Java`, сейчас на 1 маленький проект пришлось впервые столкнуться с `vb .net`.

Собственно, сам вопрос: есть ли в vb .net аналог `for (int i = 5; i > 0; i--)` на `vb .net`? На [офф. страничке](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/5ebk1751.aspx) MS про циклы в .net не нашел ничего подобного

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример из [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/5z06z1kb.aspx)

```
For number As Double = 2 To 0 Step -0.25
    Debug.Write(number.ToString & " ")
Next
Debug.WriteLine("")
```

Comment: Благодарю, плохо смотрел)

Comment: @Denis, тот цикл который смотрел - предназначен для коллекций, чтобы пробежаться по ней, так что возможно он тоже пригодится :-)